# Why can I not create a ParentNode with multiple children?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, aframe

I have the following html structure with A-Frame. Basically, I am constructing a 3D representation of an atom with the following basic html:\

```
  <a-scene>
    <a-entity id=#AtomComponent> 

      <a-sphere id=#nucleus></a-sphere> 

      <a-entity id=#electronShell>
        <a-sphere id=#electron></a-sphere>
      </a-entity>
    </a-entity>
  </a-scene>
```

To dynamically create this I am using the following javascript:

```
let sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene'); #grab the main html component

# Create the individual components
let atomComponent = document.createElement('a-entity');

let nucleus = document.createElement('a-sphere');

let electronShell = document.createElement('a-entity');

let electron = document.createElement('a-sphere');

#Append them

sceneEl.appendChild(atomComponent);

atomComponent.appendChild(nucleus);

electronShell.appendChild(atomComponent);

electron.appendChild(electronShell);
```

Maybe I'm tired but I believe that I am creating the html elements in the correct order. However when I try to execute this code I receive the following two errors:

```
material.js:170 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispose' of undefined

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'isPlaying' of null`
```

Could someone double check that my html looks legitimate? `AtomComponent` should have two children (`nucleus` and `electronShell`) with `electronShell` having only one child. Since I'm new to A-Frame and rusty on javascript I can't decide if this is an AFrame level error or a JS selector error. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: _"`AtomComponent` should have two children (`nucleus` and `electronShell`)"_ Substitute `atomComponent.appendChild(electronShell)` for `electronShell.appendChild(atomComponent)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `atomComponent.appendChild` to append both `nucleus` and `electronShell` to have multiple childs

```js
let sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene'); 

let atomComponent = document.createElement('a-entity');

let nucleus = document.createElement('a-sphere');

let electronShell = document.createElement('a-entity');

let electron = document.createElement('a-sphere');

sceneEl.appendChild(atomComponent);

atomComponent.appendChild(nucleus);

atomComponent.appendChild(electronShell);

electronShell.appendChild(electron);
console.log(document.querySelector('a-scene').outerHTML);
```

```html
<a-scene>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I am a little tired for not seeing that.